# Do not read the same index as a CSV PYTHON file

Tags: python, csv

I am doing automation on the website of the company I work for.

I have a difficulty, I think it may be simple to solve but I couldn't think of a solution to solve it.

I have this code example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import csv

URL = 'XXXXX'
URL2 = 'XXXXX'

user = 'XXXXX'
password = 'XXXXX'

filename = './geradores.csv'
def Autonomation():
    driver = webdriver.Ie()
    driver.get(URL)

    driver.find_elemen_by_name('Login').send_keys(user)
    driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)

    sleep(5)
    driver.execute_script("window.open()")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.get(URL2)
    driver.maximize_window()

    with open(filename, 'r') as writer:
         reader = csv.DictReader(writer, delimiter=';')
         for linha in reader:
             folder = linha['Pasta']
             rsc = linha['Rascunho']

             driver.find_element_by_link_text('Geradores').click()

             sleep(5)
             driver.find_element_by_name('gErador').send_keys(folder)
             driver.find_element_by_name('bloco').send_keys(rsc)
             driver.find_element_by_id('salva').click()
             driver.find_element_by_link_text('Começo').click()
if __name__ == '__main___':
   while True: # this part causes the code to reload
        try:
            Autonomation()
        execept:
            driver.quit()
            Autonomation()
```

The problem I face is that when the the code is reloaded automatically, it reads the first line of CSV again, and can´t save the same folder

Accurate When the code is automatically reloaded, it starts reading on the same line it stopped.

> example: if the code is running and is reading line 200 and the page timeout is reached the code is automatically reloaded, it will read where it left off on line 200

The number of rows in the CSV 5000K.

timeout = 40 min

I even thought of reading CSV in a separate file and calling the CSV file as a module in autonomation.

Comment: Static code in class (code outside of any method) is ran once. Calling `Autonomation()` doesn't really do anything. One thing you should probably do is using function instead of class (`def automation():` instead of `class Autonomation:`). Also, you should provide a minimal example and better explanation on what's not working. Realy hard to understand your problem.

Comment: hmmm ok so i need to put a function but my problem when the robot reloads it reloads the csv file also ends up reading it all again

Comment: well, I edited POST by putting my code in a function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I understand,

1. Your code is a "Data Entry" work.
2. You are reading CSV Data to do a web page form filling.

**Problem** is this code is not reading the data from the start when the page refreshes.

Try to read the data at once. Write to a file, for all the completed records.

**Option1:**
The simple  option - Try to split this large CSV files into smaller files. Say if you can update 550 records before a page goes for refresh then update 500 records and wait out till the page is refreshed !

**Option2:**
Can you actually have a way to check if the page is going to refresh? If it is possible then do this

Keep a counter of how many records are updated. When the page is about to refresh, save this data to a temp file.

Now update your code to check if a temp is present and then get that counter number. Skip these no.of records and continue the work

Comment: yes, it is a data entry job and you need to fill out a form. this part is all right

but the problem is that when the page refreshes, the robot reads the CSV file from the beginning.

example: [car,
truck,
airplane]

let's say the robot reads the index [truck], the site times out 40 minutes, the robot refreshes the page and reads the index [car] again

he needs to keep reading the index [truck]

Comment: The simple best option - Try to split this large CSV files into smaller files. Say if you can update 550 records before a page goes for refresh then update 500 records and wait out till the page is refreshed !

Comment: Can you actually have a way to check if page is going to refresh??

Comment: the robot updates the page by itself when it finds no value in the DOM

Comment: Try to read fro here - http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html